# Accessing ProjectOnline API ../_api/ProjectData from Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure, api, sharepoint, azure-data-factory, project-online

How is it possible to access the ../_api/ProjectData from Azure DataFactory V2? I have tried to use ClientID which was registered on the ../_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx but this seemed like a dead end.

Are there any best practices? I am quite new to ProjectOnline.

Comment: What do you mean `../_api/ProjectData`? How you use it in ADF?

Comment: The ProjectOnline's ProjectData API, I would like to use it as a source in ADF, but the I am stuck at the authentication. I am using basic auth for on-prem SSIS, but since it is going to be discontinued and we are taking steps moving to cloud the ADF would be a good option.